# The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted

Tags: internet-explorer, viewstate, asp.net

I am receiving the following error when browsing my asp.net page in internet explorer. While in firefox or mozilla, everything works fine.

I have tried different approaches as I believe there is a problem with VIEWSTATE as to:

```
 - <pages  enableViewStateMac="false" >
 - <pages enableViewState="false">
 - <pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Never">
 - <pages maxPageStateFieldLength="40">
```

But nothing seems to work. The error looks like below:

```
Source Error: 
    [No relevant source lines]
     
    Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\emportalermal\7c94fef4\cccf3353\App_Web_mtkk1qfn.6.cs    Line: 0 
    
    Stack Trace: 
    
    [FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.]
       System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
       System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +72
       System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
       System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
       System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +113
    
    [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
        Client IP: 127.0.0.1
        Port: 
        User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
        ViewState: 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...]
    
    [HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
       System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +106
       System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowViewStateError(Exception inner, String persistedState) +14
       System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +217
       System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +105
       System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +43
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6785
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +242
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +80
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
       ASP.al_page_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\emportalermal\7c94fef4\cccf3353\App_Web_mtkk1qfn.6.cs:0
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Any suggestions? Remember, the error appears only in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Are you making changes to the page via javascript? Especially any server side controls?

Comment: No not at all using javascript here. I just changed some codebehind in a usercontrol and then this problem occurred.

Comment: Sorry Oded niglected that i was using some jquery on the page and everything works fine if i comment that jquery files. Any clue how to keep both jquery and new added functionality without receiving any error ?  I have been reading so many articles on viewstate and never came to my mind that it might be a jquery problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really couldn't find a workaround for this. So I substituted jquery tabs with ajax tabs and now everything works perfect in both browsers.

Not the best solution of course but working one :)

Comment: Hi, I don't think replacement is really and answer to your question, there's plenty of alternative widgets but you didn't solve the real problem