# The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted in internet explorer

Tags: asp.net

I have used jquery for mbscrollable it working fine but when i run application in Internet Explorer it gives error on button which redirects to next page.
Error is:
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

### Server Error in '/maxnetecommerce' Application.

The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.]
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +102
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +59
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +124

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 182.72.17.210
    Port: 54486
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.1; .NET4.0C)
    ViewState: 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...]

[HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +148
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +10956310
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +11040040
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +46
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11035559
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11035098
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +91
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +240
   ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +52
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +599
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

But it works fine in Mozilla Firefox,
when i remove mbscrollable from page no error comes,
can anybody please tell me solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: see this related link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091481/the-state-information-is-invalid-for-this-page-and-might-be-corrupted might help you

Comment: This occurs to me some time, when the page date is updated through AJAX or update panel... I'm not sure why.  And it does not always show this error, only sometime...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have **a big view state**, because the mb.scrollable keep all data on the same page, and usually this data are saved on viewstate.

To test that just check the source code of your rendered html to see if viewstate are real huge.

Then if it is just change the viewstate options on web.config. You can cut it in parts automatically on web.config. You can also find code on web that compress the viewstate. You can also disable the viewstate for your control and check if you do not have other problems and you do not needed.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time we modify pages, which causes the shadow, copied files in the Temporary ASP.NET files folder to be regenerated. A user has a copy of the page that was requested before this change, and the user posts the page after the files in that folder were regenerated.

For more detail visit  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323744